# Default Border is showing while using Gridview in windows phone uwp

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp

I am displaying list of items with it's headers and content using gridview as shown below.

```
<Grid>
                            <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource src}}">
                                <GridView.GroupStyle>
                                    <GroupStyle>
                                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#2a2621" Width="400" Height="35" Margin="-10,0,-10,0">
                                                    <TextBlock x:Name="atistType" Width="200"  
                                                               Text="{Binding RegionalName}" 
                                                               Foreground="White" 
                                                               FontWeight="ExtraBold" FontSize="22" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                                    <Image Margin="110,0,10,0" 
                                                           Tag="{Binding RegionalName}" 
                                                           Tapped="RedirectToImageListing"  
                                                           Source="Assets\Right-arrow.png" 
                                                           Height="25"></Image>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                    </GroupStyle>
                                </GridView.GroupStyle>
                                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="2"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid Margin="0,5,0,5" Tag="{Binding AlbumId}" 
                                                   Tapped="RedirectToImageListOrGridView" >
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Image Width="{Binding ListingWidth}" Source="Assets/PlaceHolder.jpg"></Image>
                                                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White">
                                                    <Image Width="{Binding ListingWidth}" 
                                                   Source="{Binding SmallImage}"></Image>
                                                </Border>
                                            </Grid>                                            
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            </GridView>
                        </Grid>
```

I am able to show the data perfectly.
But, my concern is from somewhere a line is displaying like border. 
You can check in the screenshot.[image]

As shown in the screenshot, for the first image only a line is displaying like a border.
Is there a way to remove that.
I am not able to find from where the border is coming.
Thank you.

Comment: Is that the Item that has focus? In the guts of the `GridView` it uses a `ListViewItemPresenter` with properties for `FocusBorderBrush` and `FocusSecondaryBorderBrush` that are bound to theme resources by default.

Comment: If you remove this default border, how would you know this item is selected? The answer below could solve your problem, But I'm just curious, maybe you will need other effect to indicate the selected-state?

Comment: i have added some border with white color as shown. Anyway, the below answer is working fine. thanks you both of you for your effort and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<GridView>
<GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,4,4" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

[Taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162514/template-10-declaring-a-new-button-in-hamburger-navigation-and-navigating-to-it)